# Pascal's Triangle Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my first time posting... I am working on making a method to create Pascal's Triangle. I can't seem to get it to initialize the proper values, although it was printing in the format it should have been. If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great...

```
public static int[][] createPascalsTriangle(final int n)
{
  if(n < 0)
     throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Number.");

  int[][]pascal = new int [n][];

  for(int x = 0; x < pascal.length; x++)
     pascal[x] = new int[x + 1];

     pascal[0][0] = 1;

  for(int i = 0; i < pascal.length; i++)
  {
     for(int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++)
     {
        if( i > 0)
        {
           if(j==0 || j == (pascal[i].length)-1)
              pascal[i][j] = 1;
           else 
              pascal[i][j] = pascal[i-1][j] + pascal[i-1][j-1];
        }
     }


  }
  return pascal;     
 }//end createPascalsTriangle
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize all the 1's first:

Instead of

```
pascal[0][0] = 1;
```

take

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    pascal[x][0] = 1;
    pascal[x][x] = 1;
}
```

Hope I could help!

*Edit:*

I've got nowhere to write this, and I'm new to this, but somehow I'm getting such excited thinking about someone thousands of kilometres away, sitting in his/her room, and getting a relief just by bits i send that person onto the monitor. As for myself, i hopefully never lose that aspiration growing older, since helping others should make one's meaning in life.

Just wanted to take this load off me, for it is 3 in the morning here in germany and im getting tired of my homework. Take good care of yourself folks!